# Pywinauto - How to wait for TreeView till its visible

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, pywinauto

I want to wait for TreeView till it get visible by trying

```
evidence_treeview = context.new_evidence_window[u'TreeView']
 item = evidence_treeview.get_item([u'Evidence'])
 item.wait('visible', timeout=120)
```

but I am getting "AttributeError: '_treeview_element' object has no attribute 'wait'
also when I am trying by this way
wait_until(timeout=5, retry_interval=0.1, item.visible)
I am getting error
positional argument follows keyword argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typical Python error. `timeout=5` is a keyword argument because `timeout` is a keyword. All keyword arguments must be used after positional arguments (Python feature). In theory it could work so:

```
wait_until(timeout=5, retry_interval=0.1, func=item.visible)
```

But in practice it won't work because `_treeview_element` object doesn't have method `.visible()`. Correct usage is this method:

```
item.ensure_visible()
```

This method scrolls the tree view automatically to the target element. You don't need any special tricks or waits.

Comment: Thanks @Vasily Ryabov ensure_visible() is working for me